# Use UIImagePickerController for two ImageViews and upload to parse

Tags: ios, parsing, file-upload, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm really new to programming, I apologize in advance if this is a very simple question. I am trying to write a code to use `UIImagePickerController` to select two different images from my imageGallery and put it into two `UIImageView`s. Then, click a button to upload the images to Parse.

I'm having difficulty using `UIImagePickerController` twice and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Also, I'm having trouble linking it to the upload code. I've only learnt how to upload a file already in a folder, but I cant seem to work out how to link that to the `UIImagePickerController`. If you can help, it will be so much appreciated. My code so far...

```
- (IBAction)choosePhotoA:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerControllerA = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerControllerA.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerControllerA.delegate =self;

    imagePickerControllerA.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerControllerA animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage *imageA = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageViewA.image = imageA;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)uploadPhotoA:(id)sender {
    PFObject *newImage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"photos"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"]);    
    PFFile *newImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"testPhoto.png" data:imageData];    
    [newImage setObject:newImageFile forKey:@"photoUploadOne"];  

    [newImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"upload success!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: to distinguish photo A from photo B you could use a BOOL state property or verify if imageViewA.image != nil, so passing to a imageViewB. It should be done into your choosePhotoA method to centralize all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the image is picked and `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is called, you need to know which image was being picked (1 or 2). To do this, save a flag when the button is pressed which calls `choosePhotoA:`. Then, in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` you can use that flag to decide where to put the image (`imageViewA` or `imageViewB`). This would allow the user to change their mind and replace an image they already chose.

You can also save the images to disk if you want to, or use `@property`s to hold references to them (you don't really want to go and get the images back from the image views).

Now, when you want to upload, get the images (from the properties, image views or disk) and upload (basically this just changes your current use of `UIImage imageNamed:`). And you need to run the code twice to process each image.